Gitlab: Prevent running CI without semi-linear history
There is an option to prevent doing a merge without having a semi-linear history:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/methods/#merge-commit-with-semi-linear-history
(Additionally, I would like these option juste for the default branch or just the protected branches, but this is secondary)
But the CI will run anyway, mostly for nothing since it does not reflect the final result.
Is there a way to prevent running the CI without a semi-linear history?
If there was a predefined CI variable for that, we could use the worflow directive.
I am also interested in knowing if another platform has a solution for that.
I tried to look for online explanations, or look for a way of doing it myself.
The best I found was a quick fail using the first job to check the histories linearity, but this is not ideal.
